# BigQuery API [HELP]

Tags: api, google-bigquery

My spreadsheet was working normally, but this error started to appear. My account is business, so I did not activate the charge.

I've done some spreadsheets and none of them needed it.

Can someone help me?

[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV56k.png)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run the query through the web UI?

Comment: No , through the web UI working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that you do not have a billing account attached to this project and therefore you will not be able to perform querying in BigQuery of your own data until you attach a billing account. If you are saying that everything works from the UI of the Google Cloud Platform Console, you are probably using a different project there.

Comment: My company is MultiNational and I used this project and this script But in a few days began these problems. I talked with my boss and him said to me that this problem is because other partners of other country changed some thing about Billing .


Thanks

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve the problem, could you mark it as accepted so that the other members of the community could benefit from this information?